# Add Japnese Support to OCR | RPA

Tags: automation, ocr, rpa, intellibot, intellibot-studio

How can I add `Japanese language` with `OCR`?
I would like to know where the `language files` are located  and how to select them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Intellibot` supports the following `ocr engines`
Tesseract 4.0 (LSTM)
ABBYY
Abbyy Cloud
Google Cloud
Microsoft Cloud
Amazon Cloud
Modi (should be installed separately on the machine)

`Tesseract 4.0` is a good OCR engine and is free to use.
By default, the `OCR Text` component is set to use `Tesseract` with the `English` language.
The engine and language can be selected in the Ocr settings window which can be accessed by `double-clicking` on the `title` of the `OCR TEXT` component.

[image]

To use the `Japanese` language with `Tesseract`
Please download the Japanese trained data file from the link mentioned below

https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tessdata/blob/master/jpn.traineddata

then place it at the following file path

"%localappdata%\INTELLIBOT\ed611e32-2c12-4040-a1f0-4f8184df3000\0a634a0b-d535-4343-9963-23ab0d5a8702\293745f8-12ea-4a86-be5f-8cea9576f0b5\tessdata"

then `reopen Intellibot Studio`.

Now select "jpn" under Language drop-down as shown below:

[image]